# Recycle Bin Permissions

Tags: permissions, 2013, recycle-bin

How do I control who can access the **site collection** recycle bin in 2013?

I know how to control the LINK using elements.xml, but I want to control the actual page. I want to give **site owners** permission to access it without adjusting the permissions on the user or group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Site Owners only have access to the Recycle Bins at their site level. If they need access to the site collection recycle bin, they either need to be listed as a site owner for the collection in Central admin or listed as a site collection admin in the root site collection site settings.

If that isn't desirable, then the owner will have to notify the site collection admins if something needs to be recovered.

Comment: I have the Site Owners group set to full control yet when the only user in that group tries to access the bin, they are denied. Is there another setting somewhere that might be rejecting the request?

Comment: I should also note, this is the site collection level bin being accessed by a site owner, not a site collection admin.

Comment: updated my response based on the new information

Comment: @PirateEric When I goto Site Collection Administration Recycle Bin the URL changes to >>> https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/my_user_my_domain_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx

... the MY site collection has this user as the Admin. I'm wondering if this is OK because I thought then I access Site Collection Administration Recycle Bin, it shouldn't be a /personal sort of link.
This is why I can't seem to view the deleted recycle bin items for my normal users. Can you help me out?